# How to Authorization Bearer token in Java

Tags: java, api, authorization, bearer-token

I'm using Java 7.

I'm trying to access the API(https) using authorization bearer token in Java.

Here is the client code that I used:

```html
public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://example-url.com/xxx");
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    
                conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer eyXXXXXX");
    
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                String output;
    
                StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(output);
                }
    
                in.close();
                // printing result from response
                System.out.println("Response: " + response.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
```

Then I get the error response result:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
> sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation
> failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: timestamp check
> failed

How to solve it?

Comment: Make sure that your system clock is accurate and that the server has an up-to-date certificate.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I am getting this error sometimes in my custemer servers. How can I up-to-date certificates?

Comment: I already have a username and password.
How to generate token and renew certificate in code?

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using needs a secure connection to do that import the certificate for the api into your jre location using keytool command